# How does `values` work in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, apply, r5rs, callcc

From the R5RS standard:

```
Values might be defined as follows:
(define (values . things)
  (call-with-current-continuation
    (lambda (cont) (apply cont things))))
```

My first interpretation of this was that an expression like `(+ (values 1 2))` is equivalent to `(apply + '(1 2))` and would yield the result `3`. But, according to my tests, this interpretation is not correct. Here is my interpretation of the code above: `values` is a function taking any number of arguments, bundled into a list called `things`. Then, the current continuation (the place where `values` is used) is called with the list `things` "unbundled".

What am I missing? The example above `(+ (values 1 2))` gives an error or 1 depending on the interpreter I used.

Comment: I think the thing that you're missing is that `+` is not the continuation.

Comment: Good question, which shows pretty fine how awkward Scheme's `values` are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See, when you type

```
(+ (values 1 2))
```

the continuation of the call to `values` is actually *a single* argument to `+`. So, it is either treated as 1 (the first element to the list, the first value produced by the procedure), or an error. R5RS says in this regard:

> Except for continuations created by the call-with-values procedure, all continuations take exactly one value. The effect of passing no value or more than one value to continuations that were not created by call-with-values is unspecified.

On the other hand, `call-with-values` would correctly bind your list's elements to its `consumer` argument's formal arguments:

> Calls its producer argument with no values and a continuation that, when passed some values, calls the consumer procedure with those values as arguments.

Comment: Ah, I see! I tested `(+ (values 1))` and it works in the interpreter that gave an error to `(+ (values 1 2))`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand what this definition of `values` means, you need to also understand the definition of `call-with-current-continuation`, which it is defined in terms of. And helpfully, the documentation for `values` mentions `call-with-values`, as an example of how to use the result of `values`.

So, you could use `(values 1 2)` in a context like:

```
(call-with-values (lambda () (values 1 2))
                  (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
```